# Ruby -v gives me ruby 2.1.5...but rails server says I have version 2.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
Someones-iMac:john_sept_2013 Tony$ rails server
Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.5
Someones-iMac:john_sept_2013 Tony$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-darwin14.0]
```

So the console tells me I have **ruby version 2.0.0** but ruby -v tells me I have a version of **ruby 2.1.5**.

Any ideas what is going wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using rvm? Most likely you have both rvm and core ruby installed at the same time

Comment: how did you know that the conslo told you about version `2.0.0`?

Answer (score 1):

I suppouse something is wrong with the `PATH` variable.

If you use rvm try `rvm use 2.1.5` or `rbenv global 2.1.5` for rbenv and start rails again

Comment: @rmagnum2002 how many ruby version control systems do you know except rvm and rbenv?

Comment: Thanks. It appears that none are installed. But now having trouble installing RVM to as getting error
`ERROR: '/bin' is not writable - it is required for Homebrew, try 'brew doctor' to fix it!
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.`

Comment: @triathlonboy check if openssl is installed `brew install openssl` and then try `rvm autolibs read-only` if it didn't help